# why the function in side of function wont get called?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs

i have the following reactjs code to generate two dropdown list where the ddlproducts gets loaded by ddlCategories selection. but when i called the function `getDataById()` and tried to print the ajax populated array data2 to `alert()`, there was no `alert()` there were two alerts none of the alerts were prompted. it shown this error message on the IE console,

<strike>execution did not reached the function getDataById() 'cus the alert() in that function even didn't execute</strike>

> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'getDataById'

**correction:** once the calling of this.props.getDataById() was changed to this.getDataById() it worked

but how do populate the ddlProducts dropdown. how do i access  tag of the ddlProducts and then add the options to it?

here is the code:

```
var gdata=[];

var trStyle = {
    'color': 'black',
    'border-style' :'solid',
    'margin-left':'20%'
};

var HCOMP = React.createClass({
    getInitialState:function(){
    return{data1:[], data2:[], isMounted:false, selectedValue:0}
},
componentDidMount:function(){
    this.getData();
    this.setState({isMounted:true})
},
ddlProdCatsChanegeEvent: function(e) {

    if (this.state.isMounted)
    {
        var newV = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.refProdCats).value;        
        var seleValue = newV;

        this.setState({selectedValue:newV}, function(){

           this.getDataById(this.state.selectedValue);
            alert(this.state.data2);
        });
    }
},
render: function() {
    var prodCats = this.state.data1.map(function(ele, index){// <PRODCATSOPTION optValue={ele.ProductCategoryID} optText={ele.Name} />
        return <option value={ele.ProductCategoryID} data-key={index}>{ele.Name}</option>
    });

    prodCats.unshift(<option value={''}>{'---- select category ------'}</option>)

    return (<div>Prodcut Category:<br /><select id="ddlCategories"  ref="refProdCats" onChange={this.ddlProdCatsChanegeEvent}>{prodCats}</select><br />
        Products:<br /><select id="ddlPorducts" ref="refProds"></select><br /></div>
      )
},
getDataById:function(catId){
    var x = catId;
    alert('rec id:'+x);

    $.ajax({
        url:'http://localhost:53721//Home/GetProductCats?id='+ x,
        method:'GET',
        success:function(d1){
            this.setState({data2:d1});
        }.bind(this),
        error:function(){
            alert('ERROR');
        }.bind(this)
    })
},
getData:function(){
    //ajax here
    $.ajax({
        url:'http://localhost:53721//Home/GetProductCats',
        method:'GET',
        success:function(d1){
            this.setState({data1:d1});
        }.bind(this),
        error:function(){
            alert('ERROR');
        }.bind(this)
    })
}
});

var PRODOPTIONS = React.createClass({
    render:function(){
        return(<option value={this.props.optValue}>{this.props.optText}</option> )
    }

});

var PRODCATSOPTION = React.createClass({
    render:function(){
        return(<option value={this.props.optValue}>{this.props.optText}</option> )
    }

});




ReactDOM.render( <HCOMP/>,  document.getElementById('d1') );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try updating ddlProdCatsChanegeEvent to ddlPropCatsChangeEvent.

Comment: i have updated the code instead calling 'getDataById' from props i called it this.getDataById(this.state.selectedValue). good news is now all alerts display data but with my current code how do i populate the dropdown ddlPorducts. i have included refs but how do i add the collection to ddlPorducts?